# FTL: How to make a table like structure in ftl language?

Tags: freemarker

Trying to make a table like structure..

`Name                 Age
abc                    9
pqr                    14`

I am not able to indent it properly in tabular form.
My code structure is:

```
Name                          Age 
<#list (model.names) as  myname>    
${myname.name}    ${myname.age}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you generating plain text? Then things like `${foo?right_pad(20)}` can help (http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_right_pad).

Comment: `${"ab cd"?right_pad(15)}${"abcd"}
${"pqr"?right_pad(15)}${"abcd"} ` Not able to indent when there is a space in name like in "ab cd"

Comment: What do you mean it's not able to indent that? It doesn't care what the characters are, it pads to 15 characters.

Comment: That was because of some css error of "CodeMirror span".Now it is working fine.Thanks :)